# How to use HttpPost in Entity Framework Core 5 Web API with a Many to Many Relations

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, many-to-many

I'm very new with EF Core 5 but the first thing I needed to do was TO post a new item/object which has child items (Many-to-many).

I have set up my models like this:

```
public class Post
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<Post> posts { get; set; }
}
```

...and the DbContext is very simple:

```
public DbSet<Post> posts { get; set; }
public DbSet<Tag> tags { get; set; }
```

And the migrations work as expected, creating the join table automatically. But I can't figure out for the life of me how to post a new item:

This is the json ob posted by the client:

```
{
  "name": "New Post Name"
  "tags": [
    {
                    "id": 11
    },
    {
                    "id": 12
    },
    {
                    "id": 16
    },
    {
                    "id": 19
    }
  ]
}
```

The User will have entered a Name for the Post in a HTML form and selected a number of Tags available in a check box list.

....and in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Post>> PostPost(Post post)
{ 
    // can anybody help and tell me what goes in here? Cheers
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Have you created EF context already?

Comment: Thanks Sergy I have indeed :    
public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Post> posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tag> tags { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @FatGit You need to get one Tag, but why client send four Tags?

Comment: Thanks user198, I'm building a form that allows a user to submit a 'post' with a number of 'tags' multi-selected. I was expecting it to be the simplest thing in the world.

Comment: Assuming there is actual skip-navigation properties now, so you can circumvent the many-to-many dbset. 
Wouldn't it be as simple as ```await _context.Posts.AddAsync(post); await _context.SaveChangesAsync()```

Comment: Thanks a lot  @BjarkeHandsdal . Yes, your code would work to a certain extent BUT it would insert new records into the Post Table AND the Tag Table and of course the Join Table. I just need to add records to the Post Table and Join Table. I dont want the user to add/update Tags.

Comment: Arh I see, in that case you should be able to context.Posts.Update(post);

Comment: Thanks again @BjarkeHandsdal  I've tried that one but, annoyingly it updates the Tags table at the same time. And because I'm just sending Tag.Ids, Tag.names end up being updated to NULL!  This should be sooooo simple.